# How to alter taxes amounts when updating an order

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, order

I'm developing a plugin based on WooCommerce to allow ordering gift boxes. Each box is a WooCommerce product composed by multiple "alternative products" (that are made from a custom post type).
For some reasons (a box can have multiple taxe rates, etc) I need to override taxes amounts when ordering. I succeeded this step by basicaly doing this following :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'custom_calc_total', 999, 1 );
function custom_calc_total( $cart ) {
    //here I calculate amounts of differents taxes depending of what my gift boxes contain)
    
    //and here I override tax amount of the cart with my values
    $cart->set_cart_contents_taxes(
        array(
            1 => $total_tax20, //french tax 20%
            5 => $total_tax5, //french tax 5.5%
            //=> ids 1 and 5 depend of my website
        )
    );
}
```

The customer can finalise its order and if the merchant goes backend to the order panel, we can see the right amounts for taxes (I mean the custom calculated ones).
[image: right amounts]
( A : my boxes and the custom taxes amounts stored in products metas in case of ; B : the right amounts when the order is not updates yet)

But if the merchant update the order, to change the status from "pending" to "complete" for example, I think WooCommerce recalculates and updates some of the values (totals, taxes, etc). So as my woocommerce product "Gift box" is a kind of "fake product" whose values ​​(price, weight, taxes, etc) are overwritten during the buying process depending of what the box contains, when WooCommerce recalculates the results are wrong.

[image: wrong amounts]

(after the order update, the amount of tax is wrong. Here there is only shipping tax because the Box is a Woocoomerce product with a flate rate)

So, how (which hook and which function) to allow my plugin overriding taxes amounts when an order is updated as I do it during the buying process ?

I have found the hook **woocommerce_order_after_calculate_totals** , and others like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56701407/woocommerce-add-order-admin-hook-for-recalculate-button
and I have found some useful functions as $order->get_total_tax(), $order->get_cart_tax(), $order->get_tax_totals(), $order->get_taxes(), $order->set_cart_tax()
so I tried something like this :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_after_calculate_totals', 'woocommerce_order_after_calculate_totals_test', 999,2);
function woocommerce_order_after_calculate_totals_test ($and_taxes, $order){
    $order->set_cart_tax( 1000 );//change the total value of taxes and not 
    $order->save();
}
```

but I miss something and I cannot manage doing what I want.

I have also seen stuff like this if it can help, but I did not try yet. Maybe it's a track to explore ? :

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_get_tax_totals', $tax_totals, $this );
```

and

```
$order->update_meta_data( '_' . $key, $value ); ?
```

So if you have an idea it would be awesome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, I succeeded in filtering the output of the totals :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_tax_totals', 'filter_function_name_1942', 10, 2 );
function filter_function_name_1942( $tax_totals, $order ){
    
    foreach( $tax_totals as $single_tax_key => $single_tax_value ){
        if( $single_tax_value->rate_id == 1){
            $tax_totals[$single_tax_key]->amount = 1000;
            $tax_totals[$single_tax_key]->formatted_amount = wc_price('1000');
        }
    }
    
    return $tax_totals;
}
```

It's just an example with hardcoded values, but it works.

The problem I see now is that with this way the value displayed is right but the value recorded in the database is still wrong (I suppose).
I'm right ?
Is it necessary to save the good value in the database too ? if the value is used by an other plugin for example.
If yes, an idea about how to do it ? I can't find a method to save the custom value